# WEB-API OData $Batch fails after update to nightly build July 15

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I've been using a nightly build from back in June up until today. I had written a Batch handler to parse my request, and it was working. After the update, my `ParseBatchRequestsAsync` is called once for the original POST to the $batch endpoint, then receives a message that "The batch request must have 'multipart/mixed' as the media type."

When I then add an override to the `ProcessBatchAsync` method in the handler, and set a break in my original project with the June nightly build, I see this method only called once, which then calls the parse routine, all successfully.

When I do this in the July version, I see `ProcessBatchAsync` called once for the original POST to $batch, then the parse, returning the subrequests. When the subrequests are executed, I see another call to `ProcessBatchAsync`, which hits the validate routine and fails as the subrequest is not a batch, but a create/change request to an entity end point.

Here is what I can provide so far:

My batch handler looks like:

```
Imports System.Web.Http
Imports System.Web.Http.OData
Imports System.Web.Http.OData.Batch
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports Microsoft.Data.OData

Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Web.Http.Batch


Public Class CustomODataBatchHandler
    Inherits DefaultODataBatchHandler


    Public Sub New(ByVal server As HttpServer)
        MyBase.New(server)
    End Sub


Public Overrides Async Function ParseBatchRequestsAsync(request As HttpRequestMessage, ByVal cancel As CancellationToken) As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of IList(Of ODataBatchRequestItem))


    If request Is Nothing Then Throw New HttpException(400, "Bad Request")

    Dim oDataReaderSettings As ODataMessageReaderSettings = New ODataMessageReaderSettings With {.DisableMessageStreamDisposal = True, .MessageQuotas = MessageQuotas, .BaseUri = GetBaseUri(request)}
    Dim reader As ODataMessageReader = Await request.Content.GetODataMessageReaderAsync(oDataReaderSettings)
    request.RegisterForDispose(reader)

    Dim requests As List(Of ODataBatchRequestItem) = New List(Of ODataBatchRequestItem)
    Dim batchReader As ODataBatchReader = reader.CreateODataBatchReader()
    Dim batchId As Guid = Guid.NewGuid()
    Do While (batchReader.Read())

        If batchReader.State = ODataBatchReaderState.ChangesetStart Then
            Dim changeSetRequests As IList(Of HttpRequestMessage) = Await batchReader.ReadChangeSetRequestAsync(batchId)
            For Each changeSetRequest As HttpRequestMessage In changeSetRequests
                changeSetRequest.CopyBatchRequestProperties(request)
                Dim originalURI As Uri = changeSetRequest.RequestUri
                Dim reg As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\/\$[0-9]+\/")
                If originalURI.IsAbsoluteUri And reg.IsMatch(originalURI.ToString) Then
                    'original URI has a content id in it. replce base uri.
                    Dim newURI As New Uri(originalURI.ToString.Replace(Me.GetBaseUri(request).ToString, ""), UriKind.Relative)
                    changeSetRequest.RequestUri = newURI
                End If

            Next

            requests.Add(New ChangeSetRequestItem(changeSetRequests))

        ElseIf batchReader.State = ODataBatchReaderState.Operation Then

            Dim operationRequest As HttpRequestMessage = Await batchReader.ReadOperationRequestAsync(batchId, bufferContentStream:=True)
            operationRequest.CopyBatchRequestProperties(request)
            requests.Add(New OperationRequestItem(operationRequest))
        End If
    Loop

    Return requests
End Function



End Class
```

which was basically and conversion of the source to vb.net and an addition of a replace for content id handling that seemed to fix an issue with relative uri's I was having.

This handler is implemented in my webapiconfig.vb like this:
    config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", nm.GetEdmModel, New DefaultODataPathHandler, routingConventions, New CustomODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer))

If I change the requests just to submit one at a time, the controllers are called and the processing completes, so it must be something in the batch handling, likely that I am doing wrong.

**Update 07/16/2013**
Changing to the DefaultODataBatchHandler and watching for exceptions on the client side, I saw that the request was rejected with: "The batch request must have 'multipart/mixed' as the media type."

When I watch the WCF dataservices client build the request, the POST to $batch has the following headers:

```
DataServiceVersion: 1.0;NetFx
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_7b1d426d-dc36-4a6d-9d3d-be2b64b90d38
Accept: multipart/mixed
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
User-Agent: Microsoft ADO.NET Data Services
```

I tried setting it back to my handler, and can see that the requests are parsed and returned as a change set. Then the same media type error is returned to my client somewhere in the handler before my controllers are invoked.

**UPDATE 2**
I took the source for the `DefaultODataBatchHandler` and used it as a custom batch handler without changing the code. Stepping through, I see the first POST to $batch parses fine, and passes validation. When the change set of subrequests is passed to the `ExecuteRequestMessagesAsync` and then `responses.Add(await request.SendRequestAsync(Invoker, cancellationToken));` is called, `ProcessBatchRequest` is triggered again and attempts to handle the subrequest rather then allowing it to be processed by the controller. This goes into a validate and parse routine again, which fails as this is no longer a batch request, and the content type is now XML since it is the actual entity.

In order to use the Nightly build I removed everything I could find installed for MVC, WebAPI, OData, etc. and then installed all nightly packages. I wanted to include this incase it is something else causing this.

**UPDATE 3**
I overrode the ProcessBatchAsync method in my original custom batch handler in my original project and can confirm that ProcessBatchAsync ws only called once when it was working. In the current nightly build it seems the ProcessBatchAsync is called for the original request, and the subrequests. I can't confirm if this is happening only in this project, or in a new project yet.

**UPDATE 4**
Repro here: [Batch Issue Repro](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0lhRk7Y4YRaSDc3c2g0UEVGdzA/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks!

Steve

Comment: What error do you see when you use the DefaultODataBatchHandler?

Comment: Hi Kiran, With fresh eyes I tried the DefaultODataBatchHandler again. My controllers are not called, but this time I captured the exception on the client side and reviewed the inner exception, it states that "the batch request must include multipart/mixed as the mediatype". I am using the WCF dataservices client, and have set the batch option when saving changes, so need to do more digging as I'm not sure what changed.

Comment: Hello again Kiran, I have found more info. I took the source for the DefaultODataBatchHandler and all it's supporting methods and created my own Handler from it. I found that in the ExecuteRequestMessagesAsync method when it calls responses.Add(await request.SendRequestAsync(Invoker, cancellationToken)); this sends my sub request back to the batch handler, which then tries to Validate when it re-parses the batch, this time failing since my content-type is now Atom for the actual entity and it is no longer a batch request.

Comment: Not sure if you are facing issue because of this: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1135

Comment: Actually that is what the section of code with the regex match fixes above.The issue was that the URI needs to be made relative before the content id matching. This way you don't end up with the double base uri when it inserts it later in the process. My problem is that ProcessBatchAsync is being called twice. The first time when the POST to the $batch end point occurs, the second is when the invoker executes. This is the problem since the request is not a batch it fails the built-in validation.

Comment: we sense that there is a problem somewhere, but we are unable to reproduce this issue...would it be possible for you to provide a repro?...thanks.

Comment: Disregard - made it smaller and putting on my google drive. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0lhRk7Y4YRaSDc3c2g0UEVGdzA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have submitted a fix for this just now - https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/c03848bdb8efa2d0a12ab98b26a56a77396f8628. You could grab out todays nightly build to verify. Thanks for reporting the issue.